# Unable to get -depth argument to work, it is ignored with no error message

Tags: image, imagemagick

I have a folder full of Textures that are 8-bit RGB PNG files.

I want to convert them to 16-bit depth (for Microsoft Flight Simulator) and correct the size so it is a power of 2  (my example is already a power of 2).

Version is ImageMagick-7.1.1-Q16-HDRI

As a test I tried the example:

```
magick -size 640x480 -depth 16 pattern:checkerboard checkerboard.png
```

The result was a correctly sized file, with a bit depth of 4.

One of my files:

```
magick -size 512x1024 -depth 16 SolarCells_Albedo.png sc.png
```

The resulting file remains at 512x512 8 bit, but grows in file size by 309 bytes.

How do I convert images to have a 16-bit depth?

Comment: `convert a.png -depth 16 PNG48:b.png`. PNG is odd and needs the preface PNG48:

Comment: See also fuller explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47397672/2836621

Comment: Many thanks for your help.  I didn't have convert installed, but replaced it with magick and it worked.  Will I need the same syntax to change the pixel width/height to a power of 2?