# How can i tell ImageMagick to not change any color values

Tags: imagemagick, rgb, color-space

We have a PDF that is using a sRGB Colorspace. 
We try to convert the PDF in a PNG file.

We use a none palatted PNG File.

```
   magick.exe "test.pdf" -define png:color-type=6 "test.png"
```

When we convert it like this  then the RGB Colors in the source file have different values then in the destination file. We also tried to drop or asssign differnet color spaces. Nothing worked.

Is there a way to tell imageMagick to not touch the  RGB Colors and use them one to one?

Comment: You could try `magick.exe test.pdf PNG32:test.png` for RGBA or `PNG24:test.png` for RGB. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47397672/2836621 Failing that, please share a representative PDF - you can use Github, Dropbox or Google Drive.

Comment: We tried to a lot of things, and it looks like the export from Corel already changed the colors. We exported the pdf without colorprofile and thenn converted it to png, now all colors are correct.

Comment: And for those who ask "why don't we export directly to png ?"  : Corel sometimes does make a mistake with patterns so this is a workaround