# Use imagemagick "convert" function with subprocess, input image from bytesio

Tags: python, python-3.x, imagemagick, wand

I'm trying to make a distortion effect, but if we use the "convert" function using the command line, it requires us to specify the path to the file we are going to convert and at the end the name of the final image. I wanted to try to make the input image from bytesio or just bytesarray

here's my attempt but unfortunately it didn't work out(, it say like Wrong parameter: -liquid-rescale

```
# Distort function using imagemmagick
def distort(image, x=45, y=45):
    
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(image))
    w, h = img.size

    command = [
        "convert",
        "pipe:0",  # Input from stdin
        "-liquid-rescale", f"{x}x{y}%!",
        "-resize", f"{w}x{h}!",
        "pipe:1",  # Output to stdout
    ]

    try:
        process = subprocess.Popen(
            command,
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE
        )
        stdout, stderr = process.communicate(image)

        if process.returncode != 0:
            logger.info(f"ImageMagick error: {stderr.decode(encoding="latin-1")}")
            return None

        return stdout

    except Exception:
        import traceback
        traceback.print_exc()
        return None
```

Comment: Please click [edit] and add around 3 lines of `main` program that creates an image of a representative type and size - probably using `Image.new()` - and then calls your `distort()` function the way you intend to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question could do with more context showing what your images are like (size, format etc) and how you plan to use your code. If my answer is insufficient, update your question and I will try to update my answer to match.

The problem appears to be that you are using `ffmpeg`-style descriptors for input and output (i.e. `pipe:0` and `pipe:1`) rather than what **ImageMagick** expects, which is a dash/hypen, or an `fd` number. So, to read a TIFF from `stdin` and create a JPEG, use:

```
cat image.tif | magick - result.jpg
```

Or you can use:

```
cat image.tif | magick fd:0 result.jpg
```

Or you can use:

```
cat image.tif | magick /dev/stdin result.jpg
```

Note that the last option will probably not work on Windows, whereas the first 2 probably will.

---

However, that is not the whole story. You may want to force **ImageMagick** to write a JPEG or a PNG on `stdout`. You can do that by prepending a format specifier to the output file like this - note that I am redirecting to a file to avoid making a mess in your Terminal:

```
magick image.tif JPEG:-    > file.jpg
```

Or:

```
magick image.tif PNG:-     > file.png
```

Note that you can force specific types of PNG, such as 8-bit, 16-bit, palette, RGBA by reading my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47397672/2836621).

---

In concrete terms, your inner code should look more like this:

```
command = [
    "convert",
    "-",                             # Input from stdin
    "-liquid-rescale", f"{x}x{y}%!",
    "-resize", f"{w}x{h}!",
    "PNG:-",                         # Output PNG to stdout
]
```

---

Note also that there are Python bindings directly to **ImageMagick** via [wand](https://pypi.org/project/Wand/) so you can avoid all this jiggery-pokery with subprocesses using that.

Comment: Your answer is completely satisfying. But about the wand module, it has a liquid_rescale function, but in it you can't specify parameters as we specify through the console "%!" if it's wrong please correct me. So I resorted to this implementation

Comment: I have tried plenty in `wand` but I haven't tried `liquid-rescale` so I cannot say for sure. If you append `wand` as a tag to your question, maybe Eric (who did the port) will see it and reply.